# not cache image linked in stylesheet

Tags: php, javascript, css

when I am debugging to ensure that some files are not cached and therefore reloaded anew each time, I frequently link files with something like

```
<script src="script/js.js?<?=time()?>"></script>
```

Is there some way I can do something in css to ensure background images are reloaded every time the page loads without making the style something other than a .css file? (php with css header for example)

```
#bg_div{
background: url(../images/darrow.png.....)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I always control cache by htaccess if this is an option for you?

Comment: @jtheman yeah, i can do that. How would I? Thanks

Comment: While debugging you could always set the background CSS inline with Javascript and a timestamp, but to my knowledge, reloading a page should always get the newest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .htaccess like this:

```
<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT"
 </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

This prevents all images to be cached. If you put the .htaccess file in a specific folder then images in this folder doesn't get cached.

Note that on sites with heavy load cache control should be carefully planned. Using a htaccess directive like this can VASTLY affect page load times.

Comment: I know very little about htaccess. Is that just a text file I can drop into the /styles/ directory or in root directory of my entire site?

Comment: Yes it's a plain text file named exactly ".htaccess" (without quotes of course) put it in the directory with the images you want to un-cache or above.